# Dynamic where condition and column selection entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework

I have complex-type object of entity framework. 
I would like buid dynamically select and where condition . I know that is possible using expression trees , but did manage to find 
Links . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of LinqPad has a library called LinqKit, which provides a PredicateBuilder and he describes how to create dynamic expressions [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

It's pretty straight-forward and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Linq.Dynamic class help you.did you try it?

you can use it and create some string contain a query and the use it.

google about the "linq dynamic" you will find the a C# class that can use it in your app.i can email it for you ;-)

Comment: aaaa , i think so... (i am not sure)